Swap 2 lines in text file using assembler
this is my code for swapping 2 lines in DosBox assembly. I can not find out why is it printing the same thing from input.txt to out.txt. I think the problem is with line numbers (and user input). Tried by giving fixed values directly to line1 and line2 but still doesn't work. I would be grateful if anyone could fix it or at least lead me to a right direction
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
    handle      dw ? 
    handle2     dw ? 

    filename    db 26               
                db ?                
                db 26 dup(0)

    outFile     db "out.txt", 0      

    prompt1     db 13,10,"Provide filename and two line numbers, which will be swapped, E.g.: input.txt 2 3: $"

    line1       dw ?                
    line2       dw ?               

  
    buf         db 128 dup(0)        
    tempBuf     db 128 dup(0)       
    bufLen      dw ?                
    currentLine dw 1                

.code
main:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    lea dx, prompt1
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

    mov ah, 0Ah
    lea dx, filename
    int 21h

    mov si, offset filename + 1
    mov cl, [si]
    mov ch, 0
    inc cx
    add si, cx
    mov byte ptr [si], 0

    lea si, filename + 2
    call ParseLineNumbers
    jc failed

    mov ah, 3Dh
    mov al, 0
    lea dx, filename + 2
    int 21h
    jc failed
    mov handle, ax

    mov ah, 3Ch
    xor cx, cx
    lea dx, outFile
    int 21h
    jc failed
    mov handle2, ax

copy_and_swap:
    lea si, buf
    call ReadLine
    jc eof

    mov ax, currentLine
    cmp ax, line1
    je swap_with_line2

    lea si, buf
    call WriteLine
    inc currentLine
    jmp copy_and_swap

swap_with_line2:
    lea si, tempBuf
    call ReadLine

    lea si, tempBuf
    call WriteLine
    inc currentLine

    lea si, buf
    call WriteLine
    inc currentLine
    jmp copy_and_swap

eof:
    mov ah, 3Eh
    mov bx, handle
    int 21h
    mov ah, 3Eh
    mov bx, handle2
    int 21h

failed:
    mov ah, 4Ch
    int 21h


ReadLine proc
    mov ah, 3Fh
    mov bx, handle
    lea dx, buf
    mov cx, 128
    int 21h
    jc @exit
    cmp ax, 0     
    je @exit
    mov bufLen, ax
    ret
@exit:
    stc
    ret
ReadLine endp

WriteLine proc
    mov ah, 40h
    mov bx, handle2
    lea dx, buf
    mov cx, bufLen
    int 21h
    ret
WriteLine endp

ParseLineNumbers proc
    xor ax, ax
    xor cx, cx
parse_digit:
    lodsb
    cmp al, ' '
    je store_line1
    cmp al, 0
    je store_line2
    sub al, '0'
    mov bx, 10
    mov ax, cx    
    imul bx      
    mov cx, ax   
    add cx, ax
    jmp parse_digit

store_line1:
    mov line1, cx
    xor cx, cx
    jmp parse_digit

store_line2:
    mov line2, cx
    ret
ParseLineNumbers endp

end main


For starters, lea si, filename + 2; call ParseLineNumbers does not look correct. That looks like it tries to parse the file name as the line numbers.

Also your logic seems broken. You read the line into tempBuf but then write it out immediately. That will of course not swap anything.

[Edited below] "What is a text file?"

From my previous answer:

If you program ReadLine so that it accepts an address to load the line to, then the simple solution will not need to copy at all:

Now that you have included the ReadLine and WriteLine procedures, I can see that you haven't changed them to actually use that SI parameter! That's certainly one reason why you'll not see a change in the text files.
; IN (si)
ReadLine proc
    mov ah, 3Fh
    mov bx, handle
    lea dx, buf           <==== change to   MOV DX, SI
    mov cx, 128
    int 21h
    jc @exit
    cmp ax, 0     
    je @exit
    mov bufLen, ax
    ret
@exit:
    stc
    ret
ReadLine endp

; IN (si)
WriteLine proc
    mov ah, 40h
    mov bx, handle2
    lea dx, buf           <==== change to   MOV DX, SI
    mov cx, bufLen
    int 21h
    ret
WriteLine endp

Tip: first make the program work with hardcoded line numbers:
line1 dw 2
line2 dw 3

Afterwards you can add a separate input for the line number(s), so you can keep it simpler.

What is a text file?
A text file usually is a collection of sentences that are made up of characters and punctuation marks. Every sentence ends with a newline sequence that on the DOS platform is made up of the bytes 13 (carriage return) and 10 (linefeed). The length of a sentence is variable, so there's typically a mixture of short and long sentences.
What your program tries to accomplish and the solution that I have proposed until now, is totally different from the above definition of what a text file is. Your approach is rather to swap two adjacent equal-sized records from a file. It is of course still possible for such records to contain actual text characters and punctuation marks. Possibly there's even padding that was added to obtain a fixed record size like say 128.

Your current program is built upon the premise that the two lines are adjacent to each other, therefore having the user input two line numbers is kind of silly as the second line number necessarily needs to be line + 1.
Your current program also always reads 128 bytes for one line, so more logically I would consider reading anything less than 128 to be a partial record or in case 0 bytes were reported the end of the file. Partial records either constitute an error or else can be regarded as the end of the file too.
Your current program forgets to inspect the outcome of the ReadLine proc on the adjacent line. It's easy to see that there can be no swapping if the adjacent line simply doesn't exist.

By now it should be clear that you will have to find out what it truly is that your task is about. This is also really what those several downvotes are saying.

Thanks, for pointing out my mistake. I tried with hardcoded line numbers, but I made a mistake somewhere else and can't figure it out where because I still get the same results. I changed to mov dx, si also

@dodanija I edited my answer. Especially read the last paragraph.
